# Typeclasses for overloading division

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading, typeclass

I'm defining my own complex number data type as a learning exercise, and I've run into trouble overloading the `(/)` operator. It seems I can't include it in an instance of `Floating` or `Fractional`, with the compiler saying that `(/)` isn't a visible method of those classes. Is there a (preferably numeric) typeclass which will allow me to overload this operator? eg.

```
instance SOMECLASS a => SOMECLASS (Complex a) where
    (/) a b@(Complex r i) = fmap (/(r^2 - i^2)) (a * (conjugate b))
```

Here's the current implementation implementation for those interested:

```
module Complex where
data Complex a = Complex {real :: a, imaginary :: a}

i = Complex 0 1

instance Num a => Show Complex a where
    show (Complex r i)
        | i < 0 = show r ++ " - i" ++ show (negate i)
        | otherwise = show r ++ " + i" ++ show i

instance Functor Complex where
    fmap f (Complex r i) = Complex (f r) (f i)

instance Num a => Num (Complex a) where
    (+) (Complex ra ia) (Complex rb ib) = Complex (ra + rb) (ia + ib)
    (-) (Complex ra ia) (Complex rb ib) = Complex (ra - rb) (ia - ib)
    (*) (Complex ra ia) (Complex rb ib) = Complex (ra*rb - ia*ib) (ra*ib + rb*ia)

instance Floating a => Floating (Complex a) where
    (/) a b@(Complex r i) = fmap (/(r^2 - i^2)) (a * (conjugate b))

conjugate :: Num a => Complex a -> Complex a
conjugate (Complex r i) = Complex r (negate i)
```

Comment: `(/)` is defined in `RealFloat`.

Comment: `Complex.hs:20:5: ‘/’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘RealFloat’`

Comment: No in `Fractional`.

Comment: When I use `:info /` or `:i /` in ghci, I see that it’s a member of `Fractional`. Using your definition of `/` in `Fractional` compiled successfully for me, with a warning that the `fromRational` member isn’t defined. What was the error message you saw?

Comment: Yeah so far I've tried `Num`, `Fractional`, `Floating`, and `RealFloat` and got the same error each time

Comment: OT but `Num a => Show Complex a`. Why not `Show a =>`?

Comment: Oh heck, when I tried `Fractional` it gave a different error, and seems to work fine otherwise. By that point I must have skimmed over the content of the error. The error was relating to @n.m.'s comment about excluding `Show`

Comment: Sorry my bad, Fractional, not RealFloat!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type `:t (/)` in `ghci`, you will obtain:

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

So that means it is a member of `Fractional`, not `Floating`. You can thus rewrite it to:

```
instance Fractional a => Fractional (Complex a) where
    (/) a b@(Complex r i) = fmap (/(r^2 - i^2)) (a * (conjugate b))
```

And since we are nitpicking, you also have to add brackets to your `Show` instance:

```
instance Num a => Show (Complex a) where
    show (Complex r i)
        | i < 0 = show r ++ " - i" ++ show (negate i)
        | otherwise = show r ++ " + i" ++ show i
```

Comment: for `Show`, I found `a` needs to be `Num` and `Ord` in order to use `<` and `negate`, in addition to `Show`

Comment: @ZoeyHewll: ah, you are correct on that part, did not notice the comparison and `negate` call.